# How do I pass a variable into date_part function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, function, datepart

I'm passing a variable from my function into the `date_part` function but I keep getting a syntax error. Tried these 2 examples below and still got a syntax error.

#### Example 1:

`_month = date_part('month', timestamp NEW."sdate");`

#### Example 2:

`_month = date_part('month', timestamp format('%s',NEW."sdate"));`

Can anyone tell me how do I pass my variable into this function?

Comment: what is the error

Comment: `syntax error  at or near "format"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no need to  use `timestamp`  literal or `format` the string if you need to pass it to `date_part` function. If `sdate` is of type `DATE` , you may use it directly.

```
date_part('month',NEW."sdate");
```

If `sdate` is a proper date string such as '2018-01-26 13:15:20', then your first example should work fine - `date_part('month', timestamp NEW."sdate");`